# Sending A File As A Method Argument?

Tags: c#, file, variables, arguments

Is this sort of thing possible:

```
public static void DoThis(file aFile){
    //Blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can either use a stream, byte[] or a path.  Need more information.

Comment: You mean file name, file data, a reference to an open file stream?

Comment: Why didn't you try this? O.o Sure you can.

Comment: unless you define a type called `file` you will want to pass an object of type `File`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you need to do with it :)

Options include:

- path (string)
- contents (string or byte[])
- some complex object model (od your own choosing) of the contents
- FileInfo
- FileStream (or just Stream)
- some kind of reader/writer; TextReader, XmlWriter etc

Comment: If it's a posted file (from HTML input field) you could also pass the file as a `HttpPostedFile` (its class is in System.Web.dll)

Comment: maybe a short example for each option?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. If you have the file reference in the calling method, then you can definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can pass is the handle to the file i.e. reference to the file object or its contant in Binary or text format. The file object represents the handler to file and not the actual file.

Comment: C# will allow you to pass a handle to a file using `IntPtr` or `SafeFileHandle`.  However, that's a bit low level and mainly is only useful for interop.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562513/how-to-open-a-file-when-file-handle-number-is-known for discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, you can certainly do that. just remember to check for nulls....

```
public static void DoThis(file aFile)
{
    if ( aFile == null ) { // report error or whatever }
    //Blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: @Marc Gravell an instance of a class of the type "file"

Comment: @Muad'Dib: As `file` is not part of the framework, your answer strikes me as begging the question.

Comment: @Brian the OP supplied the paramaters, and it was his/her code that i was using.

Comment: @Muad'Dib: But since the OP was asking, "Is this sort of thing possible?" your answer doesn't provide any information on how to make it possible.  As the title indicates, the OP's underlying question is how to send a file as a method argument.  The code is an example of the syntax he hopes to use.

Comment: @Brian and the OP doesn't say it is a System.IO.File or some custom class, he just asks if it is possible. and, as we know, it is.